# Multiple Record Request on Servicemembers Civil Relief Act Website

Tags: database

I am a non-programmer looking for help.

I am attempting to do a multiple record SCRA search on: https://www.dmdc.osd.mil/appj/scra/scraHome.do

Essentially this is a batch upload to do many searches at one time.  The user guide asks for a .txt file, which I created, and to format the file with fixed width columns, which I also did.

Seemingly following those directions, I continue to get the file status of "All Records in Error".  This message is defined in the user guide as "File processed but no records to process further as all records erred out."

Honestly, I'm lost.  I've entered the social security number, birthdate, and last name to no avail, but I get a hit when doing the single record request.

My apologies if this is outside of the realm of questions here.

Thanks for your help,

Noah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include the Active Duty Status Date.  Positions 92-99.  This is not listed as a required field, but it is.  You can use the current date if you don't have a significant date to use.

Comment: You were right!  Thank you so much!  I was researching again and saw that the thread was answered.  Must have missed the email otherwise.